# Doesn't Java Generics upper bound rule breaks Liskov substitution?

Tags: java, generics, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

I was reading about Java Generics and following part seemed problematic:

```
public class Farm {
  private List<Animal> animals;

  public void addAnimals(Collection<Animal> newAnimals) {
    animals.addAll(newAnimals);
  }
}

farm.addAnimals(cats); // Compilation error
farm.addAnimals(dogs); // Compilation error
```

Cat and Dog are subclasses of Animal.

In order to make it work it is required to define a wildcard type with an upper bound:

```
public void addAnimals(Collection<? extends Animal> newAnimals)
```

Shouldn't I be able to use subclasses and superclasses interchangeably without needing to set an upper bound according to the definition of Liskov substition:

> Substitutability is a principle in object-oriented programming stating that an object (such as a class) and a sub-object (such as a class that extends the first class) must be interchangeable without breaking the program.

Comment: Generics are not covariant. Hence, a `Collection<Cat>` is not a `Collection<Animal>`. This does not break LSP, since LSP is not concerned with generics. We use [the PECS mnoemonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Comment: `List<Dog>`, `List<Cat>`, `Collection<Dog>`, `Collection<Cat>` etc are not subclasses of `Collection<Animal>`.

Comment: Just in case this wasn't clear, note that the types that we are substituting are not `Cat`s, `Dog`s and `Animal`s, but _collections_ of those things.

Comment: @Sweeper makes perfect sense, thanks. I'll look into PECS.

Comment: Well, the [accepted and most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301/507738) from the duplicate link nicely explains *why* it is a good thing that the compiler disallows such things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A collection of only cats is not a subclass of a collection of any animal.

This and the compilation error are good things. Otherwise, you could declare a collection of only cats, and stick a dog in it. Trouble would ensue.